# How to convert 201711 into 13th Nov 2017?

Tags: sas

Hi I am beginner is sas and I need help for this question.

I want to convert 201711 to 13th Nov 2017. I cannot understand this tricky questions.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: 201711 will never give you 13th Nov 2017. There is no day part in the date just month and year. Is this just for display purpose?

Comment: Is this home / practice work? If so, then I imagine you will have to research how SAS handles dates. If this is a genuine work requirement then it seems there is an issue with the data as it is missing the day (13).

Answer (score 0):

If this is for display purpose and assuming all date values are in the same format as that in your question then this should work.

First you create format to display the months:

```
proc format lib=work;
 value mon
     1  = "Jan"
     2  = "Feb"
     3  = "Mar"
     4  = "Apr"
     5  = "May"
     6  = "Jun"
     7  = "Jul"
     8  = "Aug"
     9  = "Sep"
     10 = "Oct"
     11 = "Nov"
     12 = "Dec"
; 
run;
```

Then you substring the month and the year from your date variable and then apply the formats.

```
data have;
length full_date $20;
  date = 201711;
  mon = input(substrn(date,5,2),best.);
  yr = input(substrn(date,1,4),best.);
  full_date = compbl(put(mon,mon.)||put(yr,best.));
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If '201711' is just some text you have to convert, then it seems the day number is missing so it will have to be added. SAS treats dates as numbers, so it is useful to convert text dates to a SAS date format. The date can then be reformatted:

```
data want;
   have    = '201711';                 /* given partial date       */
   add_day = '13';                     /* day of month to add      */
   full_dt = cats(have,add_day);       /* join day to partial date */
   num_dt  = input(full_dt,yymmdd8.);  /* convert to a SAS date    */
   text_dt = put(num_dt,date9.);       /* format as desired        */
run;
```

As you are new to SAS I have commented what each part is doing, but it would be more useful for you to understand date handling / processing in SAS, e.g. the following is a useful start:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm